# How can I resolve 'Metadata foo.dll not found!' errors when compiling C# code on the command line?

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, ui-automation

On my Windows 7 workstation, I have a variety of compilers installed - including MSVC9 and MSVC10. I recently noticed the following strange problem which only occurs in my MSVC10 environment.

In my MSVC9 shell (I use the one from the start menu), running `csc.exe` shows that it's using the C# 2008 compiler version 3.5.30729.4926 (.NET 3.5). In the MSVC10 shell, it's compiler version 4.0.30128.1. Now, the following little sample program builds with `csc.exe` as of MSVC9, but it fails with MSVC10:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Automation;

namespace UIAutomationTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I use the following command line (with MSVC9 as well as MSVC10) to build the program:

```
csc Hello.cs /r:UIAutomationClient.dll /nologo
```

With MSVC9, this succeeds (no output is printed and `Hello.exe` is built). With MSVC10, the build fails with this error message:

```
C:\src>csc Hello.cs /r:UIAutomationClient.dll /nologo
error CS0006: Metadata file 'UIAutomationClient.dll' could not be found
```

Does anybody know why that is?

**UPDATE:** I noticed that I can make the build work with MSVC10 if I modify the command line so that `/r:UIAutomationClient.dll` becomes `/r:WPF\UIAutomationClient.dll`.

Comment: Solved my problem with your update. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Where is this UIAutomationClient.dll file located relative to your cs files?

Try passing the full path of UIAutomationClient.dll.